# What is the name of this brown, cracked, oval shaped seed?

Tags: identification, houseplants, seeds

I would like to know more information about this seed. Could you please tell me the seed's name?

[image]

Here is also video of this seed on YouTube for more information https://youtu.be/AyuxpqqaZM8

Here is also the seed size: http://s9.postimg.org/lh7w5f98v/IMG_0969.jpg

Picture close to the cracked side: http://s9.postimg.org/4i3rjjxnj/IMG_0997.jpg

Comment: Hi Amin! Thanks for the clear picture! Would you mind providing more details about these seeds? I noticed you used the tag houseplants-did you find them near a plant in your house? Where do you live? What kind of plants grow in your area? Are the seeds hard or soft?  I'm asking because it will help people narrow down the choices of what they could be. The more details you give, the better answers you'll get! Have you had a look at our [help]? [ask] is a great place to start. It's nice to meet you; we hope you have fun here!

Comment: Also, how big are they?

Comment: I'm intrigued to know what they are too. I've no idea.

Comment: For me it's a nut variety, but without localization information it will be hard to identify.

Comment: Alright, First of all thanks for your reply, I found this seed in Malaysia. This seed is hard and its size is approximately 8cm width and 10cm height.

Comment: Please have a look to this: http://s9.postimg.org/lh7w5f98v/IMG_0969.jpg

Comment: Split one open, see what's inside, that might help with ID

Comment: Seed or nut, or seed with a great hard husk around it? Seeds don't usually crack open like that unless they're germinating. Split one in half along the seam, and show us what the inner seed(s) look like.

Comment: Actually bro I only have one, I don't wanna split it in half. :-) But I'll try to take a picture so close to the cracked side.

Comment: Alright, Here is the picture so close to the cracked side, please have a look:  http://s9.postimg.org/4i3rjjxnj/IMG_0997.jpg

Comment: Oh man, if I'd seen those I'd've come home with a pocketful, and tried to grow them! There's no obvious nut in there. I wonder if the little wrinkles inside contain small seeds? You could try shaking it inside a clear plastic bag. Still don't know what it is though.

Comment: Yeah I've tried before, there was no nut inside. Even I tried to grow them but have had no success. Cause I don't know what is that, maybe there's a special way to grow them, I donnu, first we need to know what this is, what's the name and how we can use for.

Comment: Where exactly did you get your sample from? The picture posted looks as if it's a crop of some sort, could this picture be from the same area? I've tried searching for Malaysia nuts but hasn't come up with anything remotely similar.

Comment: That nut I found it in out of Kuala Lumpur, on the way to Genting Highlands. but now I just only have one. that I posted an image over here. Yes bro I know there's no information about this nut on Malaysian websites. that's why I posted a question here to get to know what actually it is. cause no one knows about it.

Comment: I've been trying to see what I can find out. Hoping where you found it would narrow any search down a bit......

Comment: unfortunately there's no information about this nut in internet, maybe I'll try to go over there again, hope I'll find something, anyhow Once I got some information, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be [Cerbera Odollam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerbera_odollam), a fake mango also called *Bintaro* in Indonesia. See the pictures below. Apparently is highly toxic!

[image]

Comment: Well done, thank you for finding that one out.  Have just looked it up,too. Yes toxic, but an article in the Indian Express from a few years ago states that workers say it's gown and exported for the bio insecticides industry.  Which would make sense for the volume photographed.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing and finding that one out. Finally I found its name and thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

I think they are Marijuana Seeds

http://thebestartt.com/seeds-cannabis

Illegal in Australia.

Comment: This is abosolutely not cannabis seeds. This seeds seem to be a lot bigger while MJ seeds measure approximately 0.5 cm.

Comment: Thomas, you are correct insofar as the *exact same* photo is listed on that (somewhat dubious) website - but unfortunately it's *not* a cannabis sativa seed, neither here nor there. Looking closely, you will notice the black "standard" box used for commercial markets and similar. I'd estimate the seeds in question to be *way* bigger, at least egg-sized.